# Iterate through records and storing into an array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to display a table likes this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XSKc.png)

I need the total of Products of each month grouped by Tier. But I need to display 0 if nothing is found. I'm using

Product belongs_to :tier
Tier has_many :products

Comment: can i know your table structure

Comment: you can get this using sql query

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0qunbs20/

Answer (score 0):

you dont need iteration

if you try this you will get result in following format

```
SELECT t.name as tier ,month((f.date)) as tmonth,count(*) FROM 
 File f inner join Tier t on t.id=f.tier_id group by tier,tmonth;

TIER1 | JAN |  7  | 
TIER1 | FEB | 5   |
TIER1 |  MAR| 20  | 
TIER2 | JAN |  17 |
TIER2 |FEB  | 14  |
TIER2 |  MAR| 3   |
```

THEN

```
select tier,
  sum (case when tmonth = 'JAN' THEN cnt END) JAN,
  sum (case when tmonth = 'FEB' THEN cnt END) FEB,
  sum (case when tmonth = 'MAR' THEN cnt END) MAR,
-------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------// 12 MONTHS
FROM (SELECT tier,(SELECT t.name as tier ,month((f.date)) as tmonth,count(*) AS cnt FROM 
 File f inner join Tier t on t.id=f.tier_id group by tier,tmont) T group by tier;
```

Comment: you have to pivot 1st query result

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not quite what I need. I edited the question so you can visualize better.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in one query, just include the files.  This will preload all tier's `files` association.

In the controller, set the instance variable this way:

```
@tiers = Tier.includes(:files)
```

Add this to your Tier model

```
def months_of_files 
  files.group_by{|file| file.date.strftime("%b")}
end
```

On the index page, something like this (this syntax is HAML)

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Tier
    - (I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names")).each do |mon|
      %th= mon
  = render @tiers
```

Then in the view, when you render a tier (a row), you can do this

```
# tiers/_tier.html.haml
%tr
  %td= tier.name
  - (I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names")).each do |mon|
    %li= tier.months_of_files[mon].size
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not quite what I need. I edited the question so you can visualize better.

Comment: Do you want an HTML table?

Comment: I'll put the result into an html table